# Error in `select()`: ! Can't subset columns that don't exist. ✖ Column `Station.x` doesn't exist

Tags: r

```
rainfall_map_data <- merge(stations_df, merged_data, by = "Longitude",all = TRUE)
head(rainfall_map_data)

final_data <- rainfall_map_data %>%
            select(StationName = `Station.x`,Longitude, Latitude = Latitude.x, AverageRainfall) %>%
            distinct() %>%
            unique() # Ensure there are no duplicate rows in the data frame
```

When I render, just got the error, but the column "Station.x" is in the data, so I wanna know which part is wrong?

[image: error]

Comment: Always share a Minimum Reproducible Example.

Comment: What does `names(rainfall_map_data)` return? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.